# undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass. Friendly_id and Scaffolded controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am getting this error saying undefined method update. The show and Edit buttons work well. It's just the update that isn't working. I am using friendly_id and the controller is scaffolded with better routing.

Here is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :static_pages, except: [:show, :edit]

  devise_for :users

  mount Bootsy::Engine => '/bootsy', as: 'bootsy'

  get 'profile' => "users#profile"

  root 'indexes#index'

  get ':slug', to: 'static_pages#show'

  get ':slug/edit', to: 'static_pages#edit'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Here is the static page controller for the update method:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_static_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :static_page_params, only: [:update, :create]
  before_action :destroy_static_page, only: :destroy
  before_filter :except => [:show] do 
    redirect_to :new_user_session unless current_user && current_user.role == 5
  end

  # GET /static_pages
  # GET /static_pages.json
  def index
    @static_pages = StaticPage.all
  end

  # GET /static_pages/1
  # GET /static_pages/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /static_pages/new
  def new
    @static_page = StaticPage.new
  end

  # GET /static_pages/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /static_pages
  # POST /static_pages.json
  def create
    @static_page = StaticPage.new(static_page_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @static_page.save
        format.html { redirect_to @static_page, notice: 'Static page was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @static_page }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @static_page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /static_pages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /static_pages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @static_page.update(static_page_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @static_page, notice: 'Static page was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @static_page }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @static_page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /static_pages/1
  # DELETE /static_pages/1.json
  def destroy
    @static_page.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to static_pages_url, notice: 'Static page was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_static_page
      @static_page = StaticPage.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    end

    def destroy_static_page
      @static_page = StaticPage.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def static_page_params
      params.require(:static_page).permit(:title, :video_id, :content, :tags, :author, :date, :slug)
    end
end
```

Here are the views that have been scaffolded for the edit page:

```
%h1 Editing static_page

= render 'form'

= link_to 'Show', @static_page
\|
= link_to 'Back', static_pages_path
```

Edit: It has to do with my routes. I can't get the show button to work on the fourm bellow. I try @static_page.slug but that takes me to /page_name/page_name. When I just do @static_page it takes me to /static_page/page_name. What I need it to do is take me to /page_name.

Edit 2: Here is the form partial:

```
= simple_form_for(@static_page) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :video_id
    .bootsy_text_area
      = f.bootsy_area :content, :class => 'form-control', rows: 12
    = f.input :tags
    = f.input :author
    = f.input :date

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

Comment: Show your `form.html.erb`

Comment: Added the form partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `@static_page.update(static_page_params)`, but in this case, `@static_page` is nil.

You've defined `@static_page` as `@static_page = StaticPage.find_by_slug(params[:slug])`,  but this will return `nil` if no page with that slug is found.

There are two ways you can handle this:

- Use `find_by_slug!` instead, which will raise an exception if no record is found, or:
- Check for the presence of `nil` yourself, and decide how you want to handle it.

Comment: The problem I am having is when I click update it's taking it to /static_pages/page_site. It's supposed to go and find it at /page_site like the show does. How do I point it to this site. Likewise is there a way of making @static_page = StaticPage.find_by_slug(params[:slug]) find the object at /item instead of staticpage/item?

Comment: This is the part where you would normally go back to the tutorial you're following, and work with that :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I redid the tutorial and using find_by_slug! worked when using friendly_ID.